# Concatenate multiple zip objects into a list

Tags: python

I am using list comprehension in order to produce a number of zip objects:

```
[ zip(a, b[i]) for i in range(0, 1) ]

>>> [<zip object at 0x10a216b88>, <zip object at 0x10a216c08>]
```

How can I concatenate both zip objects into a single list?

If for example `<zip object at 0x10a216b88>` has:

```
(a, b)
(a, c)
```

and `<zip object at 0x10a216c08>`:

```
(f, g)
(f, w)
```

the desired output would be:

```
[(a, b), (a, c), (f, g), (f, w)]
```

Comment: How have you've got `<zip object at 0x10a216b88>`?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> l = [zip(range(3), range(3)), zip(range(3), range(3))]
>>> l
[<zip object at 0x7f7e80912408>, <zip object at 0x7f7e840a18c8>]
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(l))
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)]
```